# "price: missing and required" although PriceSpecification is used

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to implement Schema.org on our product pages, but I am getting an error relating to `Offer` when testing in [Google's Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/). The errors says `price` is required but I figured since I used `PriceSpecification` I didn't need to specify `price`.

Here is the error:

> [image: Google Structured Data Testing Tool: Product: 1 Error: 'price: missing and required']

Here is the format of the HTML+Microdata that I am using:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <img itemprop="image" src="https://kng.scene7.com/is/image/kng/1046-set?$prodpage$" />
    <h1 itemprop="name">Waist Apron, 11 inch</h1>
    Item# <span itemprop="mpn">1046</span>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock">
        <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
                    <td itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
                        1 - 11
                        <meta itemprop="value" content="1">
                        <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="C62">
                    </td>
                    <td>Each</td>
                    <td>
                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                        <meta itemprop="maxPrice" content="3.49">
                        $3.49
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
                    <td itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
                        12 - 29
                        <meta itemprop="value" content="12">
                        <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="C62">
                    </td>
                    <td>Each</td>
                    <td>
                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                        <meta itemprop="price" content="2.96">
                        $2.96
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
                    <td itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
                        30 - 59
                        <meta itemprop="value" content="30">
                        <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="C62">
                    </td>
                    <td>Each</td>
                    <td>
                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                        <meta itemprop="price" content="2.63">
                        $2.63
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PriceSpecification">
                    <td itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
                        60 +
                        <meta itemprop="value" content="60">
                        <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="C62">
                    </td>
                    <td>Each</td>
                    <td>
                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">
                        <meta itemprop="minPrice" content="2.44">
                        $2.44
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The odd thing is that if I just paste the `Offer` section into the Testing Tool it doesn't return the `price` error.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Note that using a `meta` element for `itemCondition` is not correct; you should use a `link` element (and omit the `itemtype`), e.g.: `<link itemprop="itemCondition" href="http://schema.org/NewCondition"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**: It’s appropriate use of Schema.org, but Google doesn’t seem to support it (yet).

Google’s documentation for their [Products Rich Snippet](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products) lists `price` as a required property. They don’t even mention the `priceSpecification` property.

So according to their documentation and their Testing Tool, it seems that Google does not (yet?) support specifying a [`priceSpecification`](http://schema.org/priceSpecification)→[`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) instead of a [`price`](http://schema.org/price).

The reason that the Testing Tool does not give this error if you only check the `Offer` is that Google has no markup feature that only uses `Offer`.
The error you get is not an actual error with your Microdata or your use of Schema.org, it’s just about what Google likes to see for displaying a Rich Snippet.

Comment: Other then making the change you suggested above, I should be good to go? Or should I change my code and remove the priceSpecification and just list them all as price?

Comment: @Nick: It depends on what you expect from Google. If you don’t care about them, you can leave it like that. But if you want Google to make use of your data (and don’t want to wait until they support `priceSpecification`, if at all), then you would want to provide `price`. However, you don’t have to remove the `priceSpecification` for that! You can use `price` *in addition*.