# How to markup a floating price product in Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I have some electronic components, and the price is floating.

For example, if you buy 5 pieces, it will be $1 each piece. and you buy 200 pieces, it will be $0.8 each pieces.

There's a order range and price sheet like this:

- 1~199 $1
- 200~500 $0.8

Can I mark this up in Schema.org (using Microdata)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with multiple [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) (or in your case probably [`UnitPriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification)) items.

The [`eligibleQuantity`](http://schema.org/eligibleQuantity) property can give the quantity range in a [`QuantitativeValue`](http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) item, with its [`minValue`](http://schema.org/minValue) and [`maxValue`](http://schema.org/maxValue) properties.

If you want to provide a [`unitCode`](http://schema.org/unitCode), you can use UN/CEFACT Common Code’s `C62`.

Based on your example (from the comment), it could look like this in Microdata:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">

<div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
  <div itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
    <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="C62" />
    <span itemprop="minValue">1</span>-<span itemprop="maxValue">100</span>: 
  </div>
  NT$<span itemprop="price">6.65</span>
</div>

<div itemprop="priceSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification">
  <div itemprop="eligibleQuantity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
    <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="C62" />
    <span itemprop="minValue">101</span>-<span itemprop="maxValue">200</span>: 
  </div>
  NT$<span itemprop="price">5.70</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried like this, but get failed. the unit price don't put into the product. Can you help me? 
<div itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Product'>
<span itemprop='name'>SG731JTTD100K</span>
<p itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification'><span itemprop='eligibleQuantity'>1 ~ 100</span></a> : <span itemprop='price'>NT$6.65</span></p>
<p itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification'><span itemprop='eligibleQuantity'>101 ~ 200</span></a> : <span itemprop='price'>NT$5.7</span></p>
</div>

Comment: @user3160227: I added an example based on this to my answer. Problems with your code: You missed a property to associate the `PriceSpecification`; you used `Product` but `priceSpecification` is defined for `Offer` (you can associate the `Offer` to the `Product` if you need it); it might be better to explicitly provide a `QuantitativeValue` item instead of relying on consumers to parse your text "1 ~ 100" correctly, or at all; the currency should not be part of `price` (use `priceCurrency` instead).

Comment: I try like that.
http://jsfiddle.net/zvh6wvz7/  
But Google structured tool told me that there is no price prop. is there something prop I missed?

Comment: @user3160227: Yes, Google [does not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31063086/1591669) support `priceSpecification` for their Rich Snippet (yet), only `price`. If you care about this Google Rich Snippet, you could add a `price` property to the `Offer` in addition (as you have different prices, you may want to use several `Offer` items; but it’s undocumented if or how Google support this).